# Applet game update screen when network gamestate changes

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, applet

I am currently following an article about a simple gameloop, I can get my game going locally and I can add a lot of objects and behavior into it.

The article is this: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8d_Game_Framework.html

My game is a grid, where other players can change some simple rectangles. It doesn't need to be the fastest approach, but somehow I need a new thread that connects to my server, and modifies the gamestate, which will get drawn on the screen. I just can't see how I can implement it, without causing the applet-thread to hang.

Can somebody see a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you having a threading problem, or are you asking how to design the communication between the server and client?

For the communication problem, here's a simple approach: have the server periodically send each player updates, whether through a constantly connected TCP connection or just periodic plain old unreliable UDP packets.  The choice of which one to use will depend on your application requirements.  Read about the difference between TCP and UDP -- there are many, many places,including on SO (just search), that discuss the tradeoffs.  Once you have the server updating on state and you can verify this works by giving the server some scripted state to follow, you can send some data the other way too. Depending on your application, you may need to be careful about security: whether a player can lie to the server about its actions, etc.

In Java, connections are often done through the Socket and ServerSocket classes, or through the DatagramPacket and DatagramSocket classes.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't clear. I am asking how to design the client. I have a server, and can manipulate state (and get updates) with a tool as simple as telnet. But I am really unsure how I should design the client with a GUI.

Comment: So, what problem are you having?  Is it that when you receive data, you need to update the screen, but that takes some time, and you don't want to miss other updates while you're busy redrawing the screen?

Comment: I need help figuring in out how to design the system. I think I need a thread that gets information about the gamestate from the server, and when it gets the gamestate, it somehow needs to tell the applet: Hey, I have updates for you, please draw this.
I don't want to miss updates while drawing.

Answer (score 1):

> I just can't see how I can implement it, without causing the applet-thread to hang.

Implement an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) to do the server update/check.  Call the listener in a loop using a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).  See [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the game only update x times a second, and not whenever there is data that have changed?

Comment: It depends on the design of the game.  E.G. If the 'enemy ship' keeps moving in a specific direction until the server sends a new command, the applet can continue moving the ship until told otherwise.  It would be a good idea to expand on what the game does, and how it works.